# Rule induction principles in Harper's PFPL

Tags: type-theory, semantics, induction, operational-semantics

I have a few small questions about section 2.4 ("Rule induction") in [Practical Foundations for Programming Languages](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/plbook/book.pdf) (p. 19).

(1) In the rule induction principles for `nat`,

> To show P(a nat) whenever a nat, it is enough to show:
>   (1) P(zero nat).
>   (2) for every a, if (a nat and) P(a nat), then P(succ(a) nat).

why is the bracketed "(*a* `nat` and)" clause necessary (and similarly for `tree`)?  This seems "natural" - we shouldn't need to prove things about syntactic entities that don't define `nat`s - but doesn't appear in the definition given of property *P* "respecting the rules" defining `nat`/`tree` (also on p. 19), which is how the rule induction principle is defined.  In the proof of Lemma 2.1, the extra "*a* nat and" part has become part of the definition of the property *P* - what's going on here?

(2) I don't understand the induction step of Lemma 2.1 (`succ(a) nat` implies `a nat`).  If I were doing this proof, I'd just invert the rules for `nat` right away, or, using Harper's property *P*, say: If `succ(a)` is of form `succ(b)`, then by injectivity, `a` equals `b`, hence `b nat` as `a nat`, but injectivity hasn't been proven yet.  It seems instead that Harper applies the induction hypothesis about `a` directly to `succ(a)` - I must be missing something.

(3) In a more naive framework, Lemma 2.3 would just follow from sufficiency of the `= nat` relation rules ("inversion"), but I don't know how to write down a proof in this style.  Why is induction even needed?

I'm sorry if these questions seem like nitpicking, but Martin-Löf/LF feels very foreign to me.  If I squint and pretend I'm doing everything in a more "traditional" operational semantics, I can read other parts of the book (with slightly different proofs), but I feel I'm missing the point in doing so.

If these questions are too tedious to answer individually, are there other references on doing semantics in this style?

Comment: It's actually on page 17.

Comment: The page number above refers to the current online version (v1.41) - it's different in the print edition.

Comment: I was referring to the online version, the page number indicated on the page, not the pdf page number.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of Section 2.4 the book explains that $\mathcal{P}(J)$ stands for a property of a *judgment* $J$. That is, the $\mathcal{P}$ in $\mathcal{P}(a\ \mathtt{nat})$ does *not* stand for a property of numbers, but a property of the judgment $a\ \mathtt{nat}$, which is the judgment that "$a$ is a number".

It just so happens that the inference rules for $a\ \mathtt{nat}$ precisely match those for numbers. Namely, the two rules defining the judgment $a\ \mathtt{nat}$ are
$$\frac{ }{\mathtt{zero}\ \mathtt{nat}}$$
and
$$\frac{a\ \mathtt{nat}}{\mathtt{succ}(a)\ \mathtt{nat}}.$$
Therefore, if we want to show that the *judgment* $a\ \mathtt{nat}$ has some property $\mathcal{P}$, then we need to show that the base case $\mathtt{zero}\ \mathtt{nat}$ has the property $\mathcal{P}$, and that whenever $\mathcal{P}(a\ \mathtt{nat})$ holds then $\mathcal{P}(\mathtt{succ}(a)\ \mathtt{nat})$ holds as well.

Or to put it the other way, the strange looking "$\mathtt{nat}$" is there because we are not talking about numbers, but about the judgments "expression $a$ satisfies the judgment $\mathtt{nat}$".

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to answer my question!  Unfortunately, I think this is the part I already understand.  But even here you disagree slightly with the the book, which also assumes $a\ \mathtt{nat}$ in addition to $\mathcal{P}(\mathtt{succ}(a)\ \mathtt{nat})$ in the induction step ... why?  And is the induction step in Lemma 2.1 obvious (how is $b\ \mathtt{nat}$ concluded?)?  Sorry for being (temporarily) so pedantic!

Comment: I think the whole point of this is to be super pedantic. Speaking off the top of my head, you might get into trouble without $a\ \mathtt{nat}$ if you use a weird $a$. I'll try to cook up a concrete example (but will also be away over the weekend, so don't hold your breath).

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

The range of acceptable inputs for the property `P` is natural numbers, and therefore if a is not a natural number `P(a)` cannot be valid. Looking at it a different way, `P(J)` is true if and only if `P(J1)`,`P(J2)`,...,`P(Jn)` are all true. If `J1` isn't true (a isn't a natural number) then `P(J1)` cannot be true, and `P(J)` cannot be true either.

**Question 2**

The presentation of the proof is a little confusing. Our goal is to show that if `succ(a)` is true, then `a nat` is true as well. In order to prove this, the book defines a property `P(a nat)` so that if `a nat` is true and we can describe `a = succ(b)`, then `b nat` must be true as well. If we can prove this property, then P(a nat) is closed. Because we are now proving `P(a nat)`, we can proceed on the assumptions `a nat` and `a = succ(b)`.

Skipping the trivial case a = 0, if `succ(a) nat` and `a = succ(b)`, then `succ(succ(b)) nat`, which implies `succ(b) nat` which in turn implies `b nat`. Thus our property `P(a nat)` holds for each of the conditions, and is therefore closed.

**Question 3**

Suppose `succ(a1) = succ(a2) nat`. By Lemma 2.1, we know `a1 nat` and `a2 nat`, leading to `a1 = a2 nat`.

Comment: I think you're right regarding Q1, although this wasn't clear to me from the book.  Regarding Q2, the second assumption in the induction step is that `succ(a)` (not `a`) has form `succ(b)`, so the prove doesn't go through.  For Q3, you've used an inversion principle? (I think you also assume the easy lemma that `a = b nat` implies `a nat` and `b nat`, since `=` and `= nat` are, _a priori_, unrelated).  But (a) can a direct inductive proof to through? (b) Harper proves his inversion principles by an appeal to induction, so my question is: is this a valid form of reasoning in this framework?

Comment: Also, (regarding your proof in Q3,) we have no proof that `a = b nat` implies that `a` is syntactically equal to (and can be substituted for) `b` ...